# Email Split Delivery

Tags: centos, email, exim, g-suite

I have 4 email accounts and out of those 4, 3 are hosted at my own server and 1 is hosted at Microsoft Exchange Online. What I would like to do is that I would like to deliver emails for those 3 email accounts which are hosted on my server locally and emails for that 1 email account to be forwarded to Microsoft Online Exchange. I was previously using Google Apps for split-delivery and it was working fine but my membership expired. I am running WHM and cPanel on a VPS running CentOS 6.

Comment: How did you set it up previously?

Comment: Using Google's split-delivery feature as those 3 emails which I am trying to host locally now, were hosted with Google Apps but as I am no longer using Google Apps for hosting those email accounts, I can't use that feature anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an alias for the address that should be delivered to the Exchange server with the domain of that server.  This would go in `/etc/aliases`.   The alias should be something like:

```
joe.exchange:  someaddress@exchange.example.com
```

Comment: Can you please add an example as well, if that's possible?

Comment: #@Mr.Flocker See revised response.